# Writing a remove method for a class implementing Iterable

Tags: java

So I have a class implementing Iterable to write a set of methods for. Most of them are pretty straightforward to think through, however, I'm having trouble writing a remove method for the class.

```
import java.util.Iterator;

public class Bag<Item> implements Iterable<Item> {

    private Item[] data = (Item[]) new Object[5];

    // The size variable keeps track of how many items
    private int size = 0;

    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder("[");
        for (Item i : this)
            b.append(i + " ");
        return b.toString() + "]";
    }

    public void expandArray() {
        int capacity = data.length * 2;
        Item[] newData = (Item[]) new Object[capacity];
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
            newData[i] = data[i];
        data = newData;
    }

    public boolean add(Item x) {
        if (size == data.length)
            expandArray();
        data[size++] = x;
        return true;
    }

    // return an Iterator for the bag
    public Iterator<Item> iterator() {
        return new BagIterator<Item>();
    }

    // Iterator class
    public class BagIterator<Item> implements Iterator<Item> {

        private int i = 0;

        public boolean hasNext() {
            return i < size;
        }

        public Item next() {
            return (Item) data[i++];
        }

    }

    public boolean contains(Item x) {
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            if (data[i] == x)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public boolean addUnique(Item x) {
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            if (data[i] == x)
                return false;
        }
        this.size++;
        this.add(x);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean remove(Item x) {

        Item lastItem = x; // holds x item
        Item swap; // holds item to swap
        int swapIndex; // holds index of item to swap

        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            if (data[i] == x) {
                // Save the last item
                lastItem = data[3];
                // Save the swapped item
                swap = data[i];
                // Save the index of swapped item
                swapIndex = i;
                // move swap item to end of list
                data[3] = swap;
                // move last item to swap pos
                data[swapIndex] = lastItem;
                // remove last item in list
                this.size--;
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        Bag<Item> b = (Bag<Item>) o;
        return false;
    }
}
```

My thoughts behind the remove method are as follows; run through the Bag, find the item to remove, take that same item and move it to the end of the bag (swapping its place with the last item in the bag), then decrease the size of the bag (thinking that it would remove it).

Now clearly there are some issues with my thinking. 1) The bag is still its original size. 2) The Bag is now unordered, which will cause a problem later on when comparing two bags.

So my question is, how can I effectively write a remove method to take an item out of my bag class without running into the issues I previously mentioned.

**Main**

```
public class Main {

    public static void main (String[] args) {

        Bag<Integer> bag = new Bag<>();

        bag.add(1);
        bag.add(2);
        bag.add(3);
        bag.add(4);

        System.out.println(bag); // [1, 2, 3, 4]

        System.out.println(bag.remove(4)); // should remove 4 and return true **WORKING
        System.out.println(bag.remove(1)); // should remove 1 and return  true **WORKING
        System.out.println(bag.remove(1)); // should NOT remove 1 and return false **NOT WORKING

        System.out.println(bag); // [4 ] 

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow I totally misread your question the first time around; I see now you're not even implementing `Iterator.remove()`. `Iterable.remove()` is *also* tricky, let's talk about that!

First off, you probably don't want to implement `Iterable` directly. It *only* lets you iterate over a sequence of elements (and optionally call `Iterator.remove()`), nothing else. Your `Bag` class should instead probably implement [`Collection`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) (or extend [`AbstractCollection`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html)) which is the general interface most Java data structures implement (it specifies `.add()`, `.remove()`, `.size()`, and so on).

The key thing to remember when creating a data structure, such as a [bag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(abstract_data_type)#Multiset), is to enforce your [invariants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_(computer_science)). Roughly speaking an invariant is a guarantee about how your data structure or method will behave. For example, every time you call `.size()` on an empty data structure it will return `0`. Once you call `.add()`, all future calls to `.size()` will return `1` (until you modify the data structure further). That's an invariant. It might seem obvious, but as your data structures get more complex these sort of simple guarantees make reasoning about your code much simpler.

Onto to your specific question. First, your idea to move the item to remove to the end is a good intuition. It's much more efficient than copying the remaining elements into new indices.

Your first concern, that the `Bag` is still the same size, is actually not a problem. Since you decrement `size` the item at the end of the array is - effectively - removed. You can set it to `null` to remove the reference but it's not necessary in terms of correctness. Instead you should look at your other methods, such as `contains()`, and make sure that they respect `size`. You should only look at indicies smaller than `size`, rather than `data.length`, because the values inbetween `size` and `data.length` may be garbage.

Your second concern, about comparing two `Bag`s, exposes another issue. Your class doesn't actually provide an invariant (there's that word again) that the array will *ever* be ordered, so re-ordering it during `.remove()` doesn't make things any worse than they were beforehand. What *is* a problem is your class doesn't override [`.equals()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) and [`.hashcode()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode--) (you have to do neither or both), meaning that *no two `Bag` instances can ever be considered equivalent*, regardless of the order of their elements. If you intend for `Bag`s to be compared you need to implement those methods correctly. Assuming you want to do that, *how* is definitely tricky. Generally speaking there is no efficient way to compare two unordered collections of objects - your only choice is to iterate over all the elements of both collections until you've verified they contain the same elements. This is O(n^2) or quadratic in performance (i.e. pretty slow).

You have two basic choices; ensure your backing array is always sorted (that's an invariant - at the end of every method the array will be sorted) or use a more efficient data structure for equality checks such as a `Set`. Both options have tradeoffs. Correctly ensuring an array is always sorted is very tricky; Java's [`TreeMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) does this and most people consider this the type of code they'd never ever want to re-implement themselves. Using a [`Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) lets you efficiently check if an element exists in your collection, but comes at the cost of preventing duplicate elements. A "bag" data structure generally permits duplicates, so using a `Set` as a backing data structure may not be acceptable for your use case. Using a `Map<E, Integer>` where the value is a count would work, but is a little more paperwork to keep track of.

Nevertheless, as a starting point a standard brute force `.equals()` implementation may be good enough. A central tenant of good software engineering is to avoid over-optimization. Start with something that works and then make it better, rather than trying to make something perfectly efficient from the get-go.

Comment: I added an equals method at the very bottom of my code, it's something that I was planning on adding. I should add that I'm required to implement these last 4 methods (contains, addUnique, remove, equals) to the existing code that was given to me in my data structures class (so I can't change anything that was given to me). Glad to hear that my first concern shouldn't be one.I will add more one more snippet of code to show specifically what I'm running into. Thanks for taking the time to go through all this!

Comment: Your `.equals()` method is problematic for a couple of reasons. Most importantly, `.equals()` is broken unless `.hashcode()` is also implemented in the same way (i.e. if `a.equals(b)` then `a.hashcode()` must equal `b.hashcode()`), but also it does worse than the default `Object.equals()` implementation, which would at least return `true` (correctly) if you try to compare the same object (`a.equals(a)`) - your implementation would return `false`, which is incorrect.

Comment: The `.equals()` method is still on my todo list, I'm aware the implementation is currently incorrect, I'll ask you to ignore that for now. I added more code example to the main. Basically, remove should be returning false if the Item is no longer in the bag, however, calling remove twice on the same item provides incorrect results, which is what initially lead me to believe that the item is not actually being removed, just hidden.

Comment: Notice that your remove method is looping over `data.length`, not `size`. The values in `data` after `size` should not be considered.

Answer (score 1):

`Iterator.remove()` is a really tricky method to get right, particularly in the face of potential concurrent modification (see [`ConcurrentModificationException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html)). If you look at the implementations of some of the standard collections you'll get some good pointers: [`ArrayList.Itr`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java#l825), [`LinkedList.ListItr`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/LinkedList.java#l871), [`HashMap.HashIterator`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java#l1405), [`TreeMap.PrivateEntryIterator`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/TreeMap.java#l1187), and [`ConcurrentSkipListMap.Iter`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListMap.java#l2272) are good starting points.

Some key things to remember:

- **Correct is more important than fast** - You can always implement `Iterator.remove()` as a call to the backing collection's `.remove()` (along with updating the `Iterator`'s state as needed). This may not be the most efficient way to solve the problem, but you'll be the most confident it works. Unless you're certain this naive implementation is a serious slow-point in your application this is likely good enough.
- **`Iterator.remove()` is an optional method** - a perfectly correct implementation is simply `throw new UnsupportedOperationException();`. It's not glamorous, but it works in the vast majority of cases. If your use case doesn't require an efficient mid-iteration-removal operation, simply leaving it unimplemented may be the smartest course of action.
- **Extend existing abstract classes** - The JDK provides a number of abstract classes as starting points (e.g. [`AbstractCollection`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html)) which provide reasonable defaults for a number of tricky methods. [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) also provides a number of [`Forwarding*` decorators](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CollectionHelpersExplained#forwarding-decorators) that can be useful when the `Abstract*` classes won't do. If you can get away with using existing behavior do so, don't reinvent the wheel.
- **Rely on shared behavior from the backing class** - one thing you'll notice looking at the JDK's `Iterator`s is that they try to do as little work as possible, preferring to outsource work to the backing class. For example suppose you can efficiently remove an element from your collection once you know it's index; define a `private void removeByIndex(int)` helper that both your `Collection.remove()` and `Iterator.remove()` methods can call. The more shared behavior you have, the less edge cases your `Iterator`s will introduce.
- **Pay attention to your invariants** - your data structure provides certain guarantees about how it behaves, and both Java (`.equals()`, `.hashcode()`) and the Collections framework (`Iterable`, `Collection`, etc.) define additional requirements. It's critical that you keep those requirements in mind when implementing helper-classes like `Iterator` implementations. If you can't be certain your optimized `Iterator` still respects the invariants the backing class provides you should scrap the optimization and just call the class's public methods.
- **Be aware of concurrent modifications** - a really useful feature of the JDK's collections is their ability to detect concurrent modifications (e.g. mid-iteration something else, even in the same thread, calls `Collection.remove()`). While your `Iterator` can technically still be correct without detecting these modifications it's much less useful, and much more likely to tolerate subtle bugs. If you're going to implement your own `Iterator` it would behoove you to try to detect changes to the backing data structure mid-iteration.

And last but not least, Guava comes with [`Multiset`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html) and [`Multimap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) implementations. Unless this is a school assignment there's no reason to implement your own [`Bag`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(abstract_data_type)#Multiset) type.

Comment: Thanks, really useful information. Unfortunately, some of the implementations you provided are extremely over my head for being a first year college student. I'm still confused on even where to start in my specific example.

Comment: Yes, the JDK classes are complex; don't feel like you need to understand them completely. They're still a great reference just to glance at; taking the time to reason out how even a small part of their classes works will be a very valuable learning experience. Thanks for the background on your experience, additional info incoming!